# Revert VS2012's Event Auto Completion back to old style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

With the following code:

```
var ddl = new DropDownList();
```

In Visual Studio 2010, when I used to type `ddl.SelectedIndexChanged+=` I could press Tab to have the IDE automatically finish the event writeup.

The same functionality still exists in VS2012, but the signature autocompletion has changed from this:

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

to

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += ddl_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Is it possible to revert back to the old style?